# Creating DataTable in PrimeFaces dynamically

Tags: excel, jsf, primefaces

I'm creating an application where user will upload excel file and application will show it in form of DataTable.
So far i have written following code by using code given [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/primefaces/datatables-with-primefaces)

```
    <h3>Dynamic Data table example</h3>
    <p:dataTable var="data" value="#{tableBean.people}">
        <p:columns value="#{tableBean.columns}" var="column"
            columnIndexVar="colIndex">
            <f:facet name="header">
            #{column.header}
            </f:facet>

        #{data[column.property]}
        </p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

Managed bean code

```
private void addPeople() {
    people = new ArrayList<People>();

    People w1 = new People("Homer Simpson","The father",48);
    People w2 = new People("Marge Simpson","The mother",46);
    People w3 = new People("Bart Simpson","Oldest child",11);
    People w4 = new People("Lisa Simpson","Sister of Bart",8);

    people.add(w1);
    people.add(w2);
    people.add(w3);
    people.add(w4);
}

private void createDynamicColumns() {

    columns = new ArrayList<ColumnModel>();
    columns.add(new ColumnModel("Name", "name"));
    columns.add(new ColumnModel("Role", "role"));
    columns.add(new ColumnModel("Age", "age"));
}
```

Getter methods are also includes.

This code is working fine but in this example I have set pattern for row namely ( Name, Role, Age) .But i don't know how many columns are there in the excel file and hence can't define the pattern of row data before hand.

Is there any way of approaching this problem?

Comment: It's depends on how you will be taking excel file. 
I done this by reading first row for header and all other rows went to data

Comment: @Darka i'm using the same approach but problem is how to manage variable number of columns

Comment: Like I said read first row and you will get number. I don't get really what is your problem.

Comment: problem is which primeface component to use if i don't know number of columns beforehand?

Comment: don't show table before file upload. I did like this: 1)Primefaces fileupload component for file upload; 2) apache POI for excel reading; 3) show table with data